# Prove that given $r \parallel s$, if t intersects r then it must intersect s

Tags: solution-verification, euclidean-geometry

Thanks for your time.

I am studying Euclidean Geometry through a text book and they have a corollary that afirms that given $r \parallel s$, if t intersects r then it must intersect s, although the proof they give is not much convinceable. It says: "If one line can intersect only one of the two parallel lines, there is one parallel line to two non-parallel lines."

A proof that seems more reasonable to me: Given $r \parallel s$. If t intersects r, but does not intersects s, then $t \parallel s$. If  $r \parallel s$ and  $t \parallel s$ than $r \parallel t$, which is a contradiction, therefore t must intersect both r and s.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: To be honest, I read both proofs as saying similar things: the book's "there is one parallel line ..." is $s$

Answer (score 1):

I must assume that two lines "intersect" when they have a point in common and they don't coincide, otherwise the claim is falsified by the case $t=r$.

As per your work, using the fact that parallelism is a transitive relation defeats the purpose of disproving the assertion that it isn't transitive (which is essentially your task).

If $r\parallel s$, $A\in r\cap t$ and $t\parallel s$, then $r$ and $t$ are both parallel lines to $s$ passing through $A$. By Euclid V, this implies $r=t$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your proof is correct.

This is another alternative:

Let $m_l$ indicates the gradient of the line $l$. Then $m_r=m_s$.

Additionally, since $t$ intersects $r$, $m_r \neq m_t$.

It follows that $m_s \neq m_t$, thus $t$ intersects $s$ at some point.